# Helix Publishing Pipeline Error - "No element in the source document matches configuration/appsettings/add'

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

Using `Sitecore 9.2`, `SXA`, and `Helix Publishing Pipeline (HPP)`.

As per the HPP documentation (https://github.com/richardszalay/helix-publishing-pipeline), we are using `Web.Helix.config` files to transform the `web.config`.

When building, I'm getting the error `No element in the source document matches configuration/appsettings/add` in the file `\obj\Debug\HelixTransformWebConfig`

I've compared our implementation to the HPP example client, and HelixBase and can't any differences. In fact, that generated `HelixTransformWebConfig` is structured the same

```
<configuration>
  <appsettings>
    <add key="Feature2.ConfigKey" value="Feature1.ConfigValue" xdt:Transform="Insert" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" />
  </appsettings>
```

Ideas?

We aren't using a namespace other than "http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" on the web.config anywhere, and our Website.wpp.targets is as requested by the documentation

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Helix Publishing Pipeline. The error indicates an issue with the  section being transformed.

Can you try the below transform for your appsettings.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Feature2.ConfigKey" value="Feature1.ConfigValue" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
```